# How to assign List<com.company.mod1.someClass> v1 to List<com.company.mod2.someClass> v2?

Tags: java

For 2 java packages, they have exactly the same structure/definition class.

Now given  List<com.company.mod1.someClass> v1, how to assign/copy to List<com.company.mod2.someClass> v2 ?

Thanks !

Comment: You have to convert the list objects in v1 from mod1.someClass to mod2.someClass.

Comment: do u have same sample code ? i'm a c developer

Comment: Can you serialize/deserialize it?  Like convert to JSON or XML then back.

Answer (score 1):

When you have two classes that look the same, but are not *actually* the same, they're still considered distinct in Java.

Consider these two examples:

```
public A {
  private int id;
  public int getId() { return this.id; }
  public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
}

public B {
  private int id;
  public int getId() { return this.id; }
  public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

While they are the "same" in that they both have the same methods and variables, they're not the "same" from the perspective of the Java compiler. You can't assign an instance of A to a variable declared with type B.

The same way, if you have a List of A, you can't assign that list to a List of B without converting, since A and B are not actually the same class.

So, assuming you have a `List<A> var1` and a `List<B> var2` and you want to add all of the A items in var1 to var2, you first need to convert them from type A to type B. You'll need a method to do the conversion. (Whether you use a class from a third-party library like Apache Commons' BeanUtils depends on what your project uses and what your feelings are on relatively large third-party utility dependencies. The example I provide below is intentionally simplified and works with the 'A' and 'B' classes I declared above.)

Here is how you might copy or assign from one list to the other, with a conversion step.

```
// Function that converts from A to B
public B convert(A a) {
  B b = new B();
  b.setId(a.getId());
  return b;
}


List<A> var1 = ...;
List<B> var2 = ...;

var1.stream()
  .map(a -> convert(a)) // converts each A in var1 to a B; simplifies to this::convert if in the same class as the method
  .forEachOrdered(var2::add); // add each item to var2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<com.company.mod2.someClass> clazzV2 = blameJudges.stream().map(this::convertToV2).collect(Collectors.toList())

////////convert

private com.company.mod2.someClass convertToV2(com.company.mod1.someClass v1) {
   com.company.mod2.someClass v2 = new com.company.mod2.someClass();
   BeanUtils.copyProperties(v1, v2);
   return v2;
}
```

Comment: What is this "BeanUtils" class?

Comment: You can find it from 'commons-beanutils'：https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.4。or 'Spring-beans': https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.2.7.RELEASE